# How are CORS preflight responses actually cached in the browser?

Tags: cors

A highly technical question, which can maybe only be answered by someone who knows browser internals...

How exactly are CORS preflight responses cached by the browser (assuming an Access-Control-Max-Age response header was returned in the response to the OPTIONS preflight request)?

Basically, in the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-result-cache-0), it says that each entry in the preflight result cache contains the following fields:

- origin
- url
- max-age
- credentials
- method
- header

(method and header are mutually exclusive)

The primary cache key is comprised of all the fields except the max-age.

So if I get a response to an OPTIONS preflight request which contains the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTION, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-cool, x-special, x-sweet
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

then am I right in thinking that this would result in **all** the following entries being added to the preflight cache?

```
http://www.example.com  <url>  3600  true  GET
http://www.example.com  <url>  3600  true  POST
http://www.example.com  <url>  3600  true  OPTIONS
http://www.example.com  <url>  3600  true  HEAD
http://www.example.com  <url>  3600  true           x-cool
http://www.example.com  <url>  3600  true           x-special
http://www.example.com  <url>  3600  true           x-sweet
```

My questions are:

1. If this is true, does that mean that it's better (from a performance POV) to return all possible allowed methods in an OPTIONS call, so they get added to the cache immediately). This is in contrast to only returning the actual method passed in the Access-Control-Request-Method request header. Or is the performance benefit so negligible that it wasn't even worth asking this question :)
2. Is there any max cache size?
3. Does anyone know why the origin and url are case-sensitive?

<rant>

FWIW, I **wish** that I could specify **Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *** (meaning that my origin server allows all headers passed to it with the actual request). Likewise, being able to specify **Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *** would be nice, so I don't need to figure out for each one whether I need to expose it to the client JS. Since they'll be passed in the response anyway, not being able to expose them is slightly pointless - sure the JS which made the CORS request can't see them, but it's not like they are hidden from a vaguely technically-knowledgeable end user - anyone using the console or Fiddler or Charles can see them.

</rant>

Sigh.

**UPDATE:** I spoke to one of the developers for Chrome, and he has confirmed that it's not possible to view the CORS cache (at least in Chrome).

**UPDATE 2:** Both **Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *** and **Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *** have been added to the fetch spec! Yay! No word on which versions of each browser (if any) support them.

Answer (score 0):

> FWIW, I wish that I could specify Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
>   (meaning that my origin server allows all headers passed to it with
>   the actual request). Likewise, being able to specify
>   Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *

A possible workaround to this is to collect all the header keys and return that in Access-Control-Expose-Headers.

Comment: Doing Access-Control-Allow-Headers is easy enough (because I can just mirror back the Access-Control-Request-Headers value, and thus allow all the headers that were passed in the request). However, to return the Access-Control-Expose-Headers, I'd need to know all the possible response headers that could be returned with the GET. If it's the same code that will process the GET that will return the OPTIONS response, then that's OK, but it means that I can't use an intermediate proxy (e.g. a CDN or a load balancer) to return them, because they have no idea about what the response headers could be